You don’t have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action'

I'm trying to deploy the templates into the azure landing zone account to adopt the cloud adoption framework concept but it's not allowing me to do.
I'm the owner and administrator of my active directory tenant...
Unable to determine the root cause of this issue.

Assign Owner role at Tenant root scope ("/") as a User Access Administrator to current user az role assignment create --scope '/' --role 'Owner' --assignee-object-id $(az ad signed-in-user show --query id --output tsv) --assignee-principal-type User

Initially, I got the same error with Owner and Global Admin role:

To resolve the error, assign Owner role at Tenant root scope ("/") to the user:
az role assignment create --scope '/' --role 'Owner' --assignee-object-id UserObjectID --assignee-principal-type User


Or use the below to get object ID of signed in user and assign role:
az role assignment create --scope '/' --role 'Owner' --assignee-object-id $(az ad signed-in-user show --query id --output tsv) --assignee-principal-type User

After assigning role, I am able to resolve the error successfully:

Or elevate the access Refer azure - User don’t have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/validate/action - Stack Overflow by Marilee Turscak - MSFT.

It's helpful, Thanks :-)
